# How can I fix this jQuery to get mouse position on scroll and make my div smoothly follow my cursor?

Tags: jquery

I've been playing around with some jQuery, trying to combine two pieces of code I've found in tutorials and stack overflow answers. I have a circular div that follows my cursor with a slight delay effect, but because I wasn't telling it to find the mouse position on scroll, it would always get left behind and then catch up when I finished scrolling.

I've managed to fix it to an extent, but it's really jerky and I'm wondering how I can make it smoother and if possible remove the delay (only on scroll).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var mouseX = 0;
  var mouseY = 0;
  var lastScrolledLeft = 0;
  var lastScrolledTop = 0;
  var xp = 0;
  var yp = 0;

  $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    captureMousePosition(event);
  })

  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    if (lastScrolledLeft != $(document).scrollLeft()) {
      mouseX -= lastScrolledLeft;
      lastScrolledLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
      mouseX += lastScrolledLeft;
    }
    if (lastScrolledTop != $(document).scrollTop()) {
      mouseY -= lastScrolledTop;
      lastScrolledTop = $(document).scrollTop();
      mouseY += lastScrolledTop;
    }
    window.status = "x = " + mouseX + " y = " + mouseY;
  });

  function captureMousePosition(event) {
    mouseX = event.pageX;
    mouseY = event.pageY;
    window.status = "x = " + mouseX + " y = " + mouseY;
  }


  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX - 20;
    mouseY = e.pageY - 20;
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    xp += ((mouseX - xp) / 3);
    yp += ((mouseY - yp) / 3);
    $("#circle").css('transform', 'translate(' + xp + 'px, ' + yp + 'px)');
  });

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: .075;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="circle" class="circle"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the scrolling problem and improve performance by using a `fixed` position for the `#circle` element, and removing the `setInterval()`. Use a `transition` on the `circle` in CSS to create the 'delayed' effect. Try the following example.

Note that you can increase/decrease the delay by amending the `transition` speed in CSS.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $circle = $('#circle');
  let half_cWidth = $circle.width() / 2;
  let half_cHeight = $circle.height() / 2;
  
  $(document).on('mousemove', e => {
    $circle.css({
      top: e.clientY - half_cHeight,
      left: e.clientX - half_cWidth
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.circle {
  position: fixed;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: .075;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: top 0.1s, left 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="circle" class="circle"></span>
```

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for this - sorry for the complete novice question, but as I already have `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`set at the top of my scripts, it seems I can't use `jQuery($ => {` Do you know how I can get it to work with the one I previously had set?

Comment: `jquery($ =>` is doc.ready, [essentially but with differences] the same as `$(function() {` - `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` is no longer the recommended way to add a doc.ready.  You can have as many doc.ready's as you like and they can even be nested.   **edit** I'm trying to find where jquery said it's no longer the standard way, learn.jquery.com still has it your way: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/  **2nd edit** here it is:  https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Hm, for some reason it's giving me the following error message - `ERROR: parsing error: Unexpected token $circle`, but only when I paste it into my own scripts under the `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` .. When I change it to `jQuery($ => {` it claims that the unexpected token is the `>` 

Comment: Are you still using IE11?  https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions  Does the snippet above work? Or give the same/similar error?  (if that works, then it's not that you're using IE11 :) )

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no worries - thought I'd just tweak it in this case as it seemed obvious that's what you meant

Comment: Hi, no I'm using google chrome / safari as browsers and dreamweaver to compose my site. Here's a screenshot of the error message - https://ibb.co/5v5v0gx

Comment: That error looks like Dreamweaver doesn't understand ES6. If you run the code in an actual browser, it will work. I'd suggest updating dreamweaver, if any are available, or even finding a newer, more capable  IDE as DW is notoriously outdated now.

Comment: Hm, I tried it and you're right, it works in most browsers, with the exception of Safari in which the cursor goes berserk and jerks around a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 things that i can suggest:

1. Use a [passive event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners) for the scroll event, this should improve the scroll performances. Unfortunatly jQuery does not implement this kind of listeners yet so you have to use the native addEventListener
2. Separate the function that you use to update the position, in this way you can call it directly without waiting for the interval in the scroll event
3. Use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of setInterval, that is the best choice for animations
4. Cache everything, those `$(document)` calls and the repeated `scrolLeft` and `scrollTop` calls are redundant and can be optimized

The resulting code is something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var mouseX = 0;
  var mouseY = 0;
  var lastScrolledLeft = 0;
  var lastScrolledTop = 0;
  var xp = 0;
  var yp = 0;
  var $doc = $(document);

  window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    var sl = $doc.scrollLeft(), st = $doc.scrollTop();
    if (lastScrolledLeft != sl) {
      mouseX += sl - lastScrolledLeft;
      lastScrolledLeft = sl;
    }
    if (lastScrolledTop != st) {
      mouseY += st - lastScrolledTop;
      lastScrolledTop = st;
    }
    window.status = "x = " + mouseX + " y = " + mouseY;
    follow();
  }, {passive:true});


  $doc.mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX - 20;
    mouseY = e.pageY - 20;
  });
  
  var follow = function() {
    xp += ((mouseX - xp) / 3);
    yp += ((mouseY - yp) / 3);
    $("#circle").css('transform', 'translate(' + xp + 'px, ' + yp + 'px)');
  };

  var followAnim = function () {
    follow();
    requestAnimationFrame(followAnim);
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(followAnim);

});
```

It seems a smooth animation for me

Comment: Hi mck89, thanks for this, it's a lot smoother. Is it possible to get it so that I can keep the slight delay when the cursor is moved but remove it so there is no delay at all when scrolling?

Comment: I've updated the code to remove the duplicated mousemove listener too. I think that what you see is not a delay in the update of the element's position because the update function is called immediately here, it's the frequency of the scroll event that cause that effect and i think there is nothing that can be done about that.